# How to open a folder in new tab in Dolphin from command-line?

Tags: kde, filemanager, dolphin, kupfer

I want to open folders with [Kupfer](http://apt%3akupfer) ([wiki](http://kaizer.se/wiki/kupfer/)) in a new tab of [Dolphin](http://apt%3adolphin) file manager but can't find a way. I suppose the next thread can help solving this: 
[Open new tab in existing Konqueror from command line](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=32104)

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/intika/kde-dolphin-single-instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented yet: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183429